# Finding commits that create new branches in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to write some automation processes related to a mercurial repository. One of the things I'd like to be able to do is identify the commits that created new branches. I can't find any easy way to do this.

I'd like to be able to get them all in one go rather than having to find a list of branch names and then for each branch name find the earliest commit.

Preferably I'd also like to have the option to only do it for open branches but that is something I can work around in other ways if needed.

Answer (score 1):

First iteration (doesn't work yet as requested: return "more than needed" changesets, handle only named branches without anonymous branching /fully legal in HG/) of
revset for log:

`children(branchpoint()) - merge() - branch(default)`

For such rather usual tree I still can't write last part of revset (eliminate revisions under "?") and think about revset() in template for filtering "bad childs" on output stage

[image: Test-repo Tree]

Second iteration, easy as "one, two, three"

I was **very** stupid and dumb, when I twisted revset-based solution. I saw it, because

```
hg log -T"{ifeq(p1.branch, branch,'','{myrev}: {sob}')}"
```

(where the last part of `ifeq()` is just my custom string with some `[templatealias]` for fun) do the trick

```
>hg log -T"{ifeq(p1.branch, branch,'','{myrev}: {sob}')}"
r4: New branch detected - two
r2: New branch detected - one
```

and is the real candidate to alias.

Testing on real repositories would be welcomed

Comment: Thanks. I'll take a look at this when I get a chance. branchpoint seems like an interesting starting point that I'd not come across before. If this proves too difficult then I can always run a command per branch - it'll just mean my program is a lot slower but it isn't particularly performance critical... I think it should be pretty easy if I already know the name of the branch to get the first commit with that name...

Comment: @Chris - single-branch revset isn't problem at all (even 2 solutions - "from head" or "from branchpoint"). It's just my dream - have all done in single command internally even without extensions

Comment: *Easiest* and shortest single-branch oneliner `hg log -r "first(branch('BRANCHNAME'))"`. Revset can be placed in parametrized revsetlias